# How can I use generics to use variable return values for my method?

Tags: java, xml, class, generics

I have an anonymous class XMLHandler with a "parseXML" method. This method is responsible for parsing an XML. The XML is source for questions for a quiz. I have different types of XMLs for different quizzes. The parseXML() provides an ArrayList which contains the particular questions. The questions are objects with a String for the question, answer,...etc. I have several classes for the questions since the quizzes are different. What I want is to use this parseXML for each XML. What you can see below is my current state. But at the line

```
currentQuestion = new ...
```

I need something like:

```
currentQuestion = new T;
```

But that doesn't work. So, what can I do?

```
XMLHandler xmlHandler = new XMLHandler(activity.getApplicationContext(), "source_quiz.xml"){

        @Override
        public <T> ArrayList<T> parseXML() throws XmlPullParserException, IOException {
            ArrayList<T> questions = null;
            int eventType = parser.getEventType();
            T currentQuestion = null;

            while(eventType != XmlPullParser.END_DOCUMENT){
                String name = null;
                switch (eventType){
                case XmlPullParser.START_DOCUMENT:
                    questions = new ArrayList<T>();
                    break;
                case XmlPullParser.START_TAG:
                    name = parser.getName();
                    if(name.equals("question")){
                        currentQuestion = new ...// new QuizQuestion();
                    } else if(currentQuestion != null){
                        if(name.equals("q")) {
                            currentQuestion.setQuestion(parser.nextText());
                        } else if(name.equals("a")){
                            currentQuestion.addAnswer(parser.nextText());
                        } else if(name.equals("c")){
                            currentQuestion.setCategory(parser.nextText());
                        } else if(name.equals("p")){
                            currentQuestion.setPage(parser.nextText());
                        } else if(name.equals("u")){
                            currentQuestion.setUnit(parser.nextText());
                        }
                    }

                    break;
                case XmlPullParser.END_TAG:
                    name = parser.getName();
                    if(name.equalsIgnoreCase("question") && currentQuestion != null){
                        questions.add(currentQuestion);
                    }
                    break;
                }
                eventType = parser.next();
            }
            return questions;
        }
    };
```

Comment: The compiler doesn't know the type of `T` until runtime; it can't tell what constructor to use with the `new` keyword.

Comment: It doesn't know the type of `T` at runtime either, due to type erasure.

Answer (score 1):

It's not allowed. As a workaround you could do this

```
public <T> ArrayList<T> parseXML(Class<T> cls) throws ...
...
        T currentQuestion = cls.newInstance();
...
```

Answer (score 1):

The first question is do you have access to modify the method signature and are you willing to do it?  If the answer is no there is no way you could do this unless you subclass the call out and take an extra value in the parameter to actually set the type of object you are interested in.

If you can modify the method signature something like this might work.

```
public <T extends IQuestion> ArrayList<T> parseXML(IQuestionFactory<T> factory) {
   //code
   T currentQuestion = factory.create();
   //code
}
```

This will take an interface that could create new objects

```
public interface IQuestionFactory<T extends IQuestion> {
   public T create();
}
```

If you are using Java 8 you could use lambdas, but I am assuming you are not using java 8.  Therefore you'd have to invoke it this way:

```
xmlHandler.parseXml(new IQuestionFactory<SpecialQuestion>() {
   @Override
   public SpecialQuestion create() {
      return new SpecialQuestion();
   }
});
```

If you cannot change the method signature perhaps you should look into subclassing XmlHandler as follows

```
public class QuestionXmlHandler<T extends IQuestion> extends XmlHandler {
    private IQuestionFactory<T> factory;

    public QuestionXmlHandler(IQuestionFactory<T> factory) {
       this.factory = factory;
    }

    public ArrayList<T> parseXML() throws XmlPullParserException, IOException {
        //code
        T currentQuestion = factory.create();
        //code
    }
}
```

You would need a new XmlHandler for each question type though.

Note you need to define IQuestion as an interface that handles the methods you plan on invoking on currentQuestion (i.e. setQuestion, setCategory, setPage, setUnit).

Comment: Intressting...can you explain it more or give an example? Where do I have to implement this Interface? etc.

Comment: Updated with a bit more details.

Comment: But how can I use a method of currentQuestion now? Like currentQuestion.setQuestion(...); Eclipse underlines it red when I do it.

Comment: I'm sorry about that.  I missed that the first time.  Please see the updated code.  Notice how T now extends IQuestion where IQuestion is an interface with methods that can be invoked on the object.